# Undefined Value in AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax

I had a function below which stores distances from two locations using google maps api. those results are stored in volunteerDist and there is a defined jid array. Document.write in line 5 showed the contents of each element in the array. Now, when I alert the Object.prototype... of volunteerDist, is says object Array. But when I called $.ajax and transferred volunteerDist into data and alert it (as shown below), it returns undefined and success (meaning data is stored but the contents are undefined). Any help? Thanks

```
function getABC(){
for(s=0;s<length;s++){
    volunteerlocation = new GLatLng(jlat[s], jlng[s]);
    volunteerDist[s] = (Math.round((eventlocation.distanceFrom(volunteerlocation) / 1000)*10)/10);
    document.write(volunteerDist[s] + '<br> ');
    document.write(jid[s] + '<br> ');
}

alert(Object.prototype.toString.call(volunteerDist));

 $.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url: 'toDistance.php',
    data : ({
        distance:volunteerDist,
        id:jid
    }),
    success: function(data){
         alert(data);
         alert('worked');
    },
   error :function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert(errorThrown);
    },
   complete : function(){
       alert('thanks');
   }
});
}
```

---

**Update:**

Below is my toDistance.php

```
<?php
    $distance=array();
    $volunteerid=array();
    if(empty($_GET)){
        echo "Hello";
    }
    else{

        $distance = isset($_GET['distance']) ? $_GET['distance'] : 0;
        $volunteerid = isset($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : 0;
        $connect = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
        mysql_select_db("mapping");


        for($i=0;$i<$distance.length;$i++){
            $updateDistance = mysql_query("
            UPDATE volunteerbio
            SET volunteerDistance = $distance[$i]
            WHERE volunteerID = $volunteerid[$i];
            ");
        }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's now the same data variable! It's in other scope.

The `data` in the success function is what the server returned. Give it other name if it confuses you.

```
$.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url: 'toDistance.php',
    data : ({
        distance:volunteerDist,
        id:jid
    }),
    success: function(result){ // Data sent from the server. not the data above!
         alert(result);
         alert('worked');
    },
   error :function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert(errorThrown);
    },
   complete : function(){
       alert('thanks');
   }
});
```

Comment: @BrandonYoung. I've no idea, There is nothing wrong with this script. You might want open a new question-thread with the server code. **This script is fine!**

Comment: i edited my question and added toDistance.php, i noticed that what I echoed in Line 5 of toDistance.php is what is alerted on the 'result'.. so this case, hello is alerted

Comment: @BrandonYoung. You're problem is you're not echoing the result from the server-php code!

Comment: @BrandonYoung. I'm not a php guy. you might get  benefits open a new question about the `php` code. cuz there's nothing wrong within the javascript part.